# Regex to match a word beginning with a period and ending with an underscore?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm quite the Regex novice, but I have a series of strings similar to this `"[$myVar.myVar_STATE]"` I need to replace the 2nd `myVar` that begins with a period and ends with an underscore.  I need it to match it exactly, as sometimes I'll have `"[$myVar.myVar_moreMyVar_STATE]"` and in that case I wouldn't want to replace anything.

I've tried things like `"\b.myVar_\b", "\.\bmyVar_\b"` and several more, all to no luck.

Comment: Assuming you mean underscore rather than semicolon; The second example still matches the listed criteria, what exempts it? The presence of a subsequent underscore before the closing ] ?

Comment: Yeah, having a subsequent underscore before the closing end bracket ] makes it be the string I don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
\[\$myVar\.([^_]+)_STATE\]
```

Matches:

```
[$myVar.myVar_STATE]            // matches and captures 'myvar'
[$myVar.myVar_moreMyVar_STATE]  // no match
```

Working regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/yM9jQ3

Or if `_STATE` was variable, you could use this: (as long as the text in the STATE part does not have underscores in it.)

```
\[\$myVar\.([^_]+)_[^_]+\]
```

Working regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/kW8oE1

**Edit:** Conforming to OP's comments below, This should be what he's going for:

```
(\[\$myVar\.)([^_]+)(_[^_]+\])
```

Regex replace example:

http://regex101.com/r/pU6yL8

C#

```
 var pattern = @"(\[\$myVar\.)([^_]+)(_[^_]+\])";
 var replaced = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "$1"+ newVar + "$3")
```

Comment: Is there a version of this that'd work if it wasn't explicitly "STATE"? There's a variety of different words that could take the place of "STATE" in my example string.

Comment: @Smoore, yes, this should work: `\[\$myVar\.([^_]+)_[^_]+\]` - http://regex101.com/r/yW8xH5

Comment: @Smoore, I see, I edited my answer to do what you're looking for.  :)

Comment: Thank you very much, you were extremely helpful, cute, and patient <3

Comment: random question, but is it your birthday today?

Comment: @Smoore, Ha! YES! It Is my birthday!! How do you know that?  :)

Comment: Happy Birthday!! I randomly had your SO profile left pulled up on my work computer from yesterday.  When I got back to work today I reloaded all my tabs and saw your age was different <3

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
\[\$myVar\.(.*?)_STATE\]
```

You can use this little trick to pick out the groups, and build the replacement at the end, like so:

```
var replacement = "something";
var input = @"[$myVar.myVar_STATE]";
var pattern = @"(\[\$myVar\.)(.*?)_(.*?)]";
var replaced = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "$1"+ replacement + "_$2]")
```

Answer (score 1):

What about something like:

> .*.(myVar_).*

This looks for anything then a . and "myVar_" followed by anything.

It matches:

> "[$myVar.myVar_STATE]"

And only the first myVar_ here:

> "[$myVar.myVar_moremyVar_STATE]"

[See it in action](http://regex101.com/r/hT1sT4).

Answer (score 1):

C# already has builtin method to do this

```
    string text = ".asda_";
    Response.Write((text.StartsWith(".") && text.EndsWith("_")));
```

Comment: How would I use to replace something like "myVar" when it's followed by "_STATE" or something in a sentence?  Such as "Here is an example of "[$myVar.myVar_SOMETHING"] in a sentence.".

Comment: the questions asks for something that ends with a '_' .. can you give me some example valid strings?

Answer (score 1):

Is Regex really required?

```
string input = "[$myVar.myVar_STATE]";
string oldVar = "myVar";
string newVar = "myNewVar";
string result = input.Replace("." + oldVar + "_STATE]", "." + newVar + "_STATE]");
```

In case `"STATE"` is a variable part, then we'll need to use Regex. The easiest way is to use this Regex pattern which matches a position between a prefix and a suffix. Prefix and suffix are used for searching but are not included in the resulting match:

```
(?<=prefix)find(?=suffix)
```

```
result =
    Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<=\.)" + Regex.Escape(oldVar) + "(?=_[A-Z]+])", newVar);
```

Explanation:

The `prefix` part is `\.`, which stand for `"."`.

The `find` part is the escaped old variable to be replaced. Regex escaping makes sure that characters with a special meaning in Regex are escaped.

The `suffix` part is `_[A-Z]+]`, an underscore followed by at least one letter followed by `"]"`. Note: the second `]` needs not to be escaped. An opening bracket `[` would have to be escaped like this: `\[`. We cannot use `\w` for word characters for the STATE-part as `\w` includes underscores. You might have to adapt the `[A-Z]` part to exactly match all possible states (e.g. if state has digits, use `[A-Z0-9]`.

Comment: I can have strings like "myVar" and "myVar_different" and would only want to replace the first "myVar" one, not the "myVar_different".

Comment: No problem, include the `"_STATE]"` part into find/replace.